# Why would one put null at the end of a function?

Tags: javascript, null

I found this in some popular library on github. Is there any sense to put `null` in the end of functions that don't return anything? Or it is just codestyle?

```
_flush(callback){    
    if(this.info.records === 0){    
        this.bom()    
        this.headers()    
    }    
    callback()    
    null     
}
```

Comment: Probably a typo and they forgot about it?

Comment: semantically, it has no effect. I can't say much more, as their code-style is so vastly different from mine, that i wouldn't understand the reason.

Comment: @adiga maybe. But 491,603 downloads and full test cover

Comment: Please add the link to the library. You should probably ask this question to the maintainers of the repo

Comment: I've seen bigger problems in bigger libraries. Also, these things sometimes have style-technical reasons. Just because it has no semantical effect, doesn't mean it's not intended.

Comment: @adiga Should/Could be this one: https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-stringify/blob/master/lib/index.js#L255

Comment: Btw, an easy first attempt at getting closer to the reason would be to look at other functions, and check, whether they all end with `null`, or similar weird parts can be observed.

Comment: @agida Yes, it is. And null in every function. And I asked the author. And I don't think it is polite to point someone to his code. I though it is like... good practice and I'm just not intelligent enough to understand the code.

Comment: If there is `null` in every function, then it's surely intended. Maybe it's to emphasize, that an implicit return is intended, or to prevent accidental mishaps with ASI, or whatever. Some non-semantically-relevant code-style reason. As mentioned above, the philosophy is so far from mine, that i wouldn't understand. I live in typescript, with all strict settings on, and the linter would even [error for that `null`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions)

Comment: It looks like the code was originally CoffeeScript which, like Ruby, implicitly returns the last value in a function. So this was probably meant to be 'return null'. (Which isn't needed in JavaScript, I don't think, because a missing return is treated as undefined I think)

Comment: @Rup It's reopened now. And Andreas has added a link to the code: https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-stringify/blob/master/lib/index.js#L255

Answer (score 2):

If you look back through the changelog you'll this library was originally written as CoffeeScript. CoffeeScript has implicit returns, meaning that if you don't return a value at the end of a function it will implicitly return the last computed value. i.e. 'null' is implicitly `return null`, and without it your flush function in CoffeeScript becomes

```js
_flush(callback){
    if(this.info.records === 0){
        this.bom()
        this.headers()
    }
    return callback()
}
```

returning the prehaps-accidentally-implicitly-returned result of callback to whoever called _flush.

So the null was probably accidentally left here when the project was ported from CoffeeScript to JavaScript, and were originally intended to prevent leaking of return values. Note that this isn't necessary in JavaScript as a function without a return statement returns undefined, which == null. Hence I think that

- for functions that don't return anything else, and where the return value isn't checked, you can just remove them
- for other functions, or where you're not sure, `return null` instead.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Moved solution from the question to an answer</sub>

> Update from the author
>
> It is totally useless, the `null` value is a leftover from coffeescript in which this library was originally written and which implicitly return the last value.